# export listview as a table in PDF form

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, pdf, export

How can I export all of the items in my listview including the column header into a PDF form?

I have already looked at [this example](http://www.e-iceblue.com/Knowledgebase/Spire.DataExport/Program-Guide/Export-Data-from-Listview-to-PDF-with-C-/VB.NET.html) but I have no idea where did the cellExport1 came from and why is the oleDbConnection1.Open(); was required when the items is already present in the listview.

I already tried posting on their forums and its been 3 days already and no one seems to have replied so I was hoping I could find answers here.

Comment: You get much better response here if you some code that enables us to continue on. See also [ask]

Comment: Try splitting up your question. From a PDF generation perspective the listview source is not relevant and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

The `oleDbConnection1.Open();` was still there since it is necessary to access the database regardless of the items being present in your listview, to trigger this activity you'll need to click your assigned button, that's why you'll notice that `oleDbConnection1.Open();` is under the `protected void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)` method.

Now the `cellExport1` I suppose contains the cells in your lisview which are to be saved in a PDF file

Hope I was able to clarify things to you!